# Convert CSV File to txt file in Python with pipe - "|"

Tags: python, text-files, opencsv

Here's my csv file

[image: csv file]

I would like to convert it to the following text file using Python (notice the '|' on the last column)

[image]

I had seen a similar code but it doesn't add the pipe (|) at the end of the last column

```
    import csv

csv_file = 'file_path.csv'
txt_file = 'file_path.txt'
with open(txt_file, "w") as my_output_file:
    with open(csv_file, "r") as my_input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(my_input_file)
        [ my_output_file.write("|".join(row)+'\n') for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Er, why wouldn't you just pop the pipe character into the string you're writing before the `\n`...? Am I missing something here? `[my_output_file.write("|".join(row)+'|\n') for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]`

Comment: Can you explain how [tag:opencsv] is related here? Its tag wiki explicitly states that questions within the tag should relate to the Java library of the same name, however I'm not seeing anything relating to Java in your question. If it's not related (as I suspect), please remove it and use tags pertinent to your question only - it's not advisable to spam unrelated tags to your question.

Comment: That's not a CSV file; it's some sort of spreadsheet application whose spreadsheet can be *exported* as a CSV file. I would figure out how to do the export properly rather than try to post-process whatever it is you are currently exporting.

Comment: It could also be a picture of an application displaying a CSV file as table. In any case, CSV is already text, so you can open it in any text editor. In any case, I wonder if you wrote that code above? Have you stepped through it or somehow tried to modify it to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

the delimiter ('|') in your case seperates each datapoint of 1 row and the line terimnator ('\n') in your case seperates each row, so adding another pipe at the end would mean adding column to all rows with a null value, but if you want do it anyway,
in the last line,
replace

```
[ my_output_file.write("|".join(row)+'\n') for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]csv.reader(my_input_file)]
```

with

```
[ my_output_file.write("|".join(row+[''])+'\n') for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).